How do you limit the base of InformationUnit
Interpreter[Restricted["Quantity", "Megabytes"]][{"1 KB", "167 MB", "1.1 GB"}]


As far as I know, this base is not $1000$, but $1024$, how to provide normal base?

Interpreter[QuantityVariable["Information"]][{"1 KB", "167 MB", "1.1 GB"}] also will provide same wraning.
